# Coupon Collector Problem for Non-Uniform Coupons: On the number of missed Coupon

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

Suppose $\mathcal B=\{1,2,\ldots,b\}$ is the set of all possible coupons, with $\mathbf p = ( p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_b)$ assigning the probability of occurrence for all coupons in $\mathcal B$.

1. The "traditional coupon collecting problem" can be summarized as follows:
   Assume we have a variable numbers $n$ of draws  from a non-depleting set of coupons (urn with coupons distributed as $\mathbf p$). We can count the drawn numbers of coupons according the different kinds of coupons in $\mathcal B$ with a occupancy vector $(X_1,X_2,..X_b)$, with $X_i$ is the number of coupons from type $i$, and $\sum_i X_i=n$. **A prominent problem investigate in $\mathbb E[n]$, i.e. expected number of needed to fulfill a constraint on minimal quotas $X_i \geq q_i$, with predefined quotas $\mathbf q = ( q_1,q_2,...,q_b)$.** Investigated, e.g. in [[1](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v15i1n31/pdf),[2](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v20i2p33/pdf)].
2. **A kind twisted problem I am interested in is the following:**
   Assume we have a fixed number of $N$ draws from the urn of coupons with non-uniform distribution $\mathbf p$, can estimate or bound the number of coupon-types, which we will not observe in our $N$ draws? To be more formal, let $Y_i$ be an indicator variable with $Y_i=1$ for $X_i=0$ otherwise $Y_i=0$, and we are interested in $\mathbb E[G]$, where $G=\sum_i Y_i$.Evidently, for uniform distribution the expected number of vacancies in the occupancy vector will be minimal.

In fact I am interested in bounding $\mathbb E[G]$ incorporating an information theoretic measure on $\mathbf p$, e.g. the entropy of the distribution $\mathbf p$, the total variation distance of $\mathbf p$ to uniform distribution or maybe some useful f-divergence. At least some bound dependend on maybe $\max_i p_i$ and $\min_i p_i$ would be helpful.

If you have any idea how to tackle my problem, I am glad to hear your advice or answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198857/coupon-collector-problem-for-non-uniform-coupons-bound-on-the-number-of-missed/198988#198988

Comment: i am a bit confused, is the audience of the math.stackexchange and mathoverflow the same? should i remove this post, as it's a doublicate?

Comment: When you post a duplicate, at least you should up front say so!  And, no, you should not now remove it.  There is a certain intersection between the audiences, I dont know how large.

Comment: Sorry, as you can see, i am quite new to this community and not familiar with the etiquette and good practice, yet. But I try my very best with future posts. Thanks again, for pushing me in the right direction, again ; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to calculate $\mathbb{E}[G]$ using linearity of expectation. We have $\mathbb{E}[Y_i] = \Pr[X_i=0] = (1-p_i)^N$. Therefore $$\mathbb{E}[G] = \sum_{i=1}^b (1-p_i)^N.$$ Whether you can bound it in terms of any other functions of $\mathbf{p}$ is up to you.

Comment: @user2888219 Just play with the data you are given and try to obtain the best bound you are able to.

Comment: okay. thanks for this precise answer. maybe you can give me some further hint. apparently we have $m (1-1/b)^N \leq \mathbb E[G]$ and further $ \| \mathbf 1 - \mathbf p|_\infty \leq \mathbb E[G] \leq m \| \mathbf 1 - \mathbf p|_\infty$ as trivial bounds with $\mathbf 1 $ as $m$-dimensional all-one vector. i need more structure in $\mathbf p$  to limit $\mathbb E[G]$ more specificly. what's about: a) $\| \mathbf 1/b - \mathbf p\|_1 < \rho_1$ or more strict with b) $| 1/b - p_i| < \rho_2$. would this help in tightening the limits?

Comment: maybe you have some reference for me, as i don't know for what to search exactly. but, i am sure there are some results about the distance from uniform distribution, at least in textbooks.

Comment: @user2888219 You may be right that somewhere some such bound can be found. But these bounds are usually not too difficult to obtain using standard techniques. I suggest you give it a shot. Usually the tricks are the Cauchy–Schwartz inequality and Jensen's inequality.

Comment: _"I suggest you give it a shot"_ - okay. thanks again, yuval.